# Wordpress: Comment on Archive Pages

Tags: wordpress, comments, archive, woocommerce

I'm currently developing a Wordpress site/theme for a client.

He has a specific requirement to be able to add comments to an archive page - it actually needs to be a comment on the page itself, rather than the posts/products within that archive.

I effectively need a way to add comments.php to the bottom of archive.php, although I understand this won't work because an archive page doesn't have an ID for the comments to associate with.

Is there any way to give a category archive page an ID based on the category, and then hook the comments template into this ID for each archive?

Thanks so much in advance for any advice you can offer - it's been a long process and this is the last bit remaining to finalise the project!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: So far I have tried that standard <?php comments_template; ?>, although this didn't show anything up at all. After reading up on the web, I came across this instead: <?php global $withcomments; $withcomments = 1; comments_template(); ?>. This displayed the reviews section correctly, and allowed me to add a review (I'm within a woocommerce loop, so comments are called reviews), however these comments were assigned to a random product within the archive, rather than the archive itself. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: It does. Comments, unfortunately, are attached to specific Post/Page IDs. An Archive is typically some kind of Post Type or Taxonomy that encapsulates multiple posts. I usually advise against this kind of approach because I generally find it a bit sloppy, but you can set up a Page Template that queries the Archive you're looking for, and then utilize the Comments Template for the Page itself. After setting up a Page that uses this template, you should have what you need. Try this approach, and when you have some code to show us, we can help you if you're having trouble.

Comment: Thanks Maio - problem is, there's over 400 categories, so creating a page template for each individual archive would be a real ball-ache! Plus archives/categories will be constantly added by the client, with each one needing it's own comments, so from what I understand, this wouldn't be a suitable approach unfortunately.

Comment: That said, I have just come across and managed to get a third party comment system, IntenseDebate to work and behave as I require. Whilst it's not ideal (it would be nice to manage everything (including comments) within the Wordpress dashboard, it seems like this is going to be the most suitable approach.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question, then, since I'm sure it will help future visitors.

Comment: Have done so, thanks for your help maiorano :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it would seem this isn't directly possible, however for anyone who would like to do something similar, there is a third party comment solution called **IntenseDebate** which is suitable to be added to the archive pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you use DISQUS, you can call the comments template using PHP to bypass WordPress checks and have comments on archives pages.

```
include 'comments.php';
```